# How to resize the Image control to fill horizontally and vertically resize the same amount

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, resize

I wanted to resize an image control so that the width will be filled and the height equivalent the same amount. The result will be a squared shape.

What do I override if I required to inherit the image control.

Answer (score 2):

As your requirement , do you mean you want the Image control has the same value of WidthRequest and HeightRequest. And you can resize it?

You don't need to override the image control, just use data binding to bind the WidthRequest and HeightRequest to the same value.

For example:

```
<Image BindingContext="{x:Reference MySlider}" x:Name ="MyImg" WidthRequest="{Binding Value}" HeightRequest="{Binding Value}" BackgroundColor="Red"></Image>

<Slider Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MySlider" Maximum="360"></Slider>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXogr.gif)

Comment: Do u mean if I have a scrollview where the image is hosting inside. I wanted to have the image fill entire width of the scrollview and have the height the same dimension as the the width of itself.

Comment: <Image BindingContext="{x:Reference MyImg}" x:Name ="MyImg" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="{Binding WidthRequest}" BackgroundColor="Red"></Image>

Comment: U can also binding itself attributes "WidthRequest"  to HeightRequest and set the WidthRequest value  fill the entire width